# OSGI bundle error - Unresolved constraint in bundle 4: package; (package=com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.parsers)

Tags: maven-2, osgi

I am new to OSGI bundle development. I am trying to create a bundle using Maven script, when I deploy it, i am getting the following error

```
*BundleProvisioningResourceLocator->error: Unable to handle Bundle: [bundle-jar-file-name].jar. Bundle state: UPDATED
org.osgi.framework.BundleException: Unresolved constraint in bundle 4: package; (package=com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.parsers)
 at org.apache.felix.framework.Felix.resolveBundle(Felix.java:3090)
 at org.apache.felix.framework.Felix.startBundle(Felix.java:1439)
 at org.apache.felix.framework.BundleImpl.start(BundleImpl.java:774)
 at org.apache.felix.framework.BundleImpl.start(BundleImpl.java:755)
 ......
 at javax.swing.AbstractButton.fireActionPerformed(Unknown Source)
 at javax.swing.AbstractButton$Handler.actionPerformed(Unknown Source)
 at javax.swing.DefaultButtonModel.fireActionPerformed(Unknown Source)
 at javax.swing.DefaultButtonModel.setPressed(Unknown Source)
 at javax.swing.AbstractButton.doClick(Unknown Source)
 at javax.swing.AbstractButton.doClick(Unknown Source)
 at javax.swing.plaf.basic.BasicMenuItemUI$Actions.actionPerformed(Unknown Source)
 at javax.swing.SwingUtilities.notifyAction(Unknown Source)
 at javax.swing.JComponent.processKeyBinding(Unknown Source)
 at javax.swing.JMenuBar.processBindingForKeyStrokeRecursive(Unknown Source)
 at javax.swing.JMenuBar.processBindingForKeyStrokeRecursive(Unknown Source)
 at javax.swing.JMenuBar.processBindingForKeyStrokeRecursive(Unknown Source)
 at javax.swing.JMenuBar.processKeyBinding(Unknown Source)
 at javax.swing.KeyboardManager.fireBinding(Unknown Source)
 at javax.swing.KeyboardManager.fireKeyboardAction(Unknown Source)
 at javax.swing.JComponent.processKeyBindingsForAllComponents(Unknown Source)
 at javax.swing.JComponent.processKeyBindings(Unknown Source)
 at javax.swing.JComponent.processKeyEvent(Unknown Source)
 at java.awt.Component.processEvent(Unknown Source)
 at java.awt.Container.processEvent(Unknown Source)
 at java.awt.Component.dispatchEventImpl(Unknown Source)
 at java.awt.Container.dispatchEventImpl(Unknown Source)
 at java.awt.Component.dispatchEvent(Unknown Source)
 at java.awt.KeyboardFocusManager.redispatchEvent(Unknown Source)
 at java.awt.DefaultKeyboardFocusManager.dispatchKeyEvent(Unknown Source)
 at java.awt.DefaultKeyboardFocusManager.preDispatchKeyEvent(Unknown Source)
 at java.awt.DefaultKeyboardFocusManager.typeAheadAssertions(Unknown Source)
 at java.awt.DefaultKeyboardFocusManager.dispatchEvent(Unknown Source)
 at java.awt.Component.dispatchEventImpl(Unknown Source)
 at java.awt.Container.dispatchEventImpl(Unknown Source)
 at java.awt.Window.dispatchEventImpl(Unknown Source)
 at java.awt.Component.dispatchEvent(Unknown Source)
 at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEvent(Unknown Source)
 at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpOneEventForFilters(Unknown Source)
 at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForFilter(Unknown Source)
 at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForHierarchy(Unknown Source)
 at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(Unknown Source)
 at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(Unknown Source)
 at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.run(Unknown Source)*
```

I tried to google for solution with no success!

Any pointers to solve it would be helpful.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Check your bundle manifest for Import-Packages. The package imported by your bundle is not exported in OSGi framework.
2. If you like to parse XML in your bundle - use approach from OSGi Compendium services spec: 702 Chapter: XML Parser Specification.

Comment: Thanks for the tips, indeed it was the problem with package not being exported. The root cause of the problem was class path conflicts!